# Xgboost cv evaluation metric - unbalanced data

Tags: logistic, classification, boosting

I'm using Xgboost for some binary classification and so it makes sense for me to use log loss as my evaluation metric within cross validation.

My data is highly unbalanced though. Would log loss still be relevant? Is there a better metric for unbalanced data?

Comment: Log loss measures the compatability of estimated probabilities against the true outcomes. Since it is probabilistic, it does not suffer from class imbalance.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the AUC metric, since you are using xgboost. Also, you can try F1 metric, however it's a custom metric:

```
def xg_f1(y,t):
    true = t.get_label()
    y_bin = [1 if y_cont > 0.5 else 0 for y_cont in y]
    return 'f1',f1_score(true,y_bin)
```

Comment: Since you recommend using the AUC, I assume you believe log loss is not relevant for highly unbalanced data. Is that correct? (Note that that is the OP's question.) Can you explain why unbalanced data makes log loss irrelevelant & how using the AUC addresses that problem? At present, it isn't clear that this is actually an answer to the stated question (I suspect it might be, but it isn't clear).